# How to convert this obj-c code to swift (NSArray with NSDictionary)

Tags: objective-c, swift

So I'm trying to convert some obj-c code into swift and I came upon this which I don't understand how to convert to swift.

If I'm correct the next lines read like: Put the outcome of `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]` in a new array named `nameOfArray` and make a new dictionary named `nameOfDictionary` out of the value of `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]`.

```
NSArray *nameOfArray = (NSArray*)dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT];

NSDictionary *nameOfDictionary = dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT];
```

Comment: What is the type of your `Dictionary`, is it `[String:Any]`? What is the type of `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]`, is it `[Any]`?

Comment: type of Dictionary is [String,NSNumber]

Comment: And the type of dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT] = NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> NSArray *nameOfArray = (NSArray*)dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT];
> ```
>
> If I'm correct the next lines read like: Put the outcome of `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]` in a new array named `nameOfArray`

If you know Swift and not Objective-C you may be thinking that arrays are value types, so an assignment from one array into a `var` creates a new array. However in Objective-C arrays are *reference* types and assignment of an `NSArray *` value doesn't create a new array, it just copies a reference to an existing array.

The above line of code copies the value associated with key `SOME_CONSTANT` in the dictionary `dictionary` into the variable `nameOfArray`, and that value is a reference to an array. After this assignment both `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]` and `nameOfArray` reference the *same* array.

> ```
> NSDictionary *nameOfDictionary = dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT];
> ```
>
> and make a new dictionary named `nameOfDictionary` out of the value of `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]`.

As above no new dictionary is made, this line does the same thing as the first one - it copies a reference value stored in the dictionary into a variable, only in this case the line says the value is a reference to a dictionary.

If the above two lines are what is actually in your code and not a simplified version then you have a problem: the first line says `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]` has an `NSArray *` value while the second says it has an `NSDictionary *` value – and something cannot be both a dictionary and an array. However you go on to say in the comments:

> type of `dictionary` is `[String,NSNumber]`

which states that the values in the dictionary are neither `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` references but `NSNumber` references, but then you say:

> And the type of `dictionary[SOME_CONSTANT]` = `NSDictionary`

So not `NSArray` or `NSNumber`...

So you have a lot of type mismatches and nobody can really help you unless you show the actual code, the actual types of everything, and explain exactly what you are stuck with. Don't try to edit this question, it already has a negative vote, ask a new one giving the details and someone will probably help you along. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation CRD. This alone helped me a lot.